# I want to reference one dimension in another one but use an operator on it

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, dimension

As in the title I want one dimension referenced in another one but want to use an operator on it. Something like this

```
<dimen name="corner_radius">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="correction_for_corner_radius">-"@dimen/corner_radius"</dimen>
```

or this

```
android:layout_marginBottom=-"@dimen/corner_radius"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you can't just using XML. The `@dimen/corner_radius` is actually just an ID, so negative of that is not what you want.

I'd recommend instead doing it at runtime, e.g. setting margin bottom in your Java / Kotlin to:

```
-getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius)
```

Comment: I know its just an ID I just hoped theres a way to use operators on what the ID references. I feel like the way to do it in Java is a bit of a waste of resources so I'll just stick to the predefined values. Thanks for the clarification tho.

Answer (score 0):

The [data binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) supports expressions. Please try to use the same.